# if I call an async operation in one view controller and the user moves to the next view controller, does the async call finish

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsoperationqueue, sdwebimage

On my first screen, I want to load and cache several JSON calls and image calls. If the user clicks onto the second view controller before they finish,
will these calls be cancelled or will they finish?

sample call in AFNetworking:

```
  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
  manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
  NSString *arcURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/arc/v1/api/locations/%i/mobile_home",MYHost(), locationID];
  [manager GET:arcURL parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {

  // on return will get written to a cache
```

sample call in SDWebImage

```
    NSURL *imageURL=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[mi objectForKey:@"instore_image_url"]];
  SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
  [manager downloadWithURL:imageURL
                   options:0
                  progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
   {
     // progression tracking code
   }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
   {
     if (image)
     {
        // image downloaded - just writing to cache
     }
   }];
}
```

Comment: In general you are responsible for stopping it, the rest depends on implementation.

Comment: you can check that by setting a breakpoint or a NSLog call

Comment: so switching ViewControllers would cause them to continue running? I'm basically preloading and writing to cache so need them but not at that point.

Comment: I would think the calls would be executed since they are asynchronous and run on a background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GET`, `POST`, etc., methods of `AFHTTPSessionManager` return `NSURLSessionTask` references. If you leave the controller that initiated the request, the request will continue unless you (a) save a reference to that `NSURLSessionTask` object; and (b) explicitly call the `cancel` method for that object.

SDWebImage method `downloadWithURL` likewise returns a reference (in this case, an object that conforms to `SDWebImageOperation` protocol), which you can `cancel` if you want to.

Comment: Correct. The same is true for SDWebImageManager.